# Simple regex problem: Removing all new lines from a file

Tags: python, regex

I'm becoming acquainted with python and am creating problems in order to help myself learn the ins and outs of the language.  My next problem comes as follows:

I have copied and pasted a huge slew of text from the internet, but the copy and paste added several new lines to break up the huge string.  I wish to programatically remove all of these and return the string into a giant blob of characters.  This is obviously a job for regex (I think), and parsing through the file and removing all instances of the newline character sounds like it would work, but it doesn't seem to be going over all that well for me.

Is there an easy way to go about this?  It seems rather simple.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The two main alternatives: read everything in as a single string and remove newlines:

```
clean = open('thefile.txt').read().replace('\n', '')
```

or, read line by line, removing the newline that ends each line, and join it up again:

```
clean = ''.join(l[:-1] for l in open('thefile.txt'))
```

The former alternative is probably faster, but, as always, I strongly recommend you MEASURE speed (e.g., use `python -mtimeit`) in cases of your specific interest, rather than just assuming you know how performance will be.  REs are probably slower, but, again: don't guess, MEASURE!

So here are some numbers for a specific text file on my laptop:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"import re" "re.sub('\n','',open('AV1611Bible.txt').read())"
10 loops, best of 3: 53.9 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit "''.join(l[:-1] for l in open('AV1611Bible.txt'))"
10 loops, best of 3: 51.3 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit "open('AV1611Bible.txt').read().replace('\n', '')"
10 loops, best of 3: 35.1 msec per loop
```

The file is a version of the KJ Bible, downloaded and unzipped from [here](http://printkjv.ifbweb.com/AV_txt.zip) (I do think it's important to run such measurements on one easily fetched file, so others can easily reproduce them!).

Of course, a few milliseconds more or less on a file of 4.3 MB, 34,000 lines, may not matter much to you one way or another; but as the fastest approach is also the simplest one (far from an unusual occurrence, especially in Python;-), I think that's a pretty good recommendation.

Comment: How about string.strip()? i.e. python -mtimeit "''.join(l.strip() for l in open('AV1611Bible.txt'))"

Comment: That has different semantics, since it would remove leading and trailing spaces, which is NOT part of the specs (even rstrip would still remove trailing spaces, again outside the specs). Anyway, both are very marginally slower than using l[:-1], by about 3%, repeatably.

Answer (score 10):

I wouldn't use a regex for simply replacing newlines - I'd use `string.replace()`.  Here's a complete script:

```
f = open('input.txt')
contents = f.read()
f.close()
new_contents = contents.replace('\n', '')
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
f.write(new_contents)
f.close()
```

Comment: Nice, the new line is inside single quotes. Does that matter in Python?

Comment: Strings can use single or double quotes in Python - they're equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
re.sub(r"\n", "", file_contents_here)
```

Comment: so i'm going to have to manually open the file, read it character for character into a string, do a sub and write back to the file character by character?

Comment: or better re.sub("[\n\r]+", "", file-contents);

Comment: @Chris: `open(fname).read()` gives you a string, after filtering you can write it as `open(fname2, 'w').write(output_sting)`. What exactly character by character means?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a python learning problem, but if you're ever trying to do this from the command-line, there's no need to write a python script. Here are a couple of other ways:

```
cat $FILE | tr -d '\n'

awk '{printf("%s", $0)}' $FILE
```

Neither of these has to read the entire file into memory, so if you've got an enormous file to process, they might be better than the python solutions provided.

Comment: Not python, but +1 for mentioning the large file problem, which is always good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but since it was in my search results for a similar query, and no one has mentioned the python string functions `strip() || lstrip() ||  rstrip()`, I'll just add that for posterity (and anyone who prefers not to use re when not necessary):

```
old = open('infile.txt')
new = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
stripped = [line.strip() for line in old]
old.close()
new.write("".join(stripped))
new.close()
```

Comment: The non-use of `strip()` and `lstrip()` _were_ discussed in the comments about Martelli's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1249740/355230).

Answer (score 0):

All the examples using `<string>.replace('\n','')` is the correct method to remove all carriage returns.

If you are interested in removing all redundant new lines for debugging etc., here is how:

```
import re
re.sub(r"(\n)\1{2,}", "", _your_string).strip()
```